# Alphabetically sort LinkedList without using Collections by first and last name in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write code which creates a linked list of names in alphabetical order from a file.

The names must be ordered by last name, then first name. The second layer of sorting is where I am having trouble.

I'm including my code so far, and right now I'm just trying to rewrite `sortList` so that it goes through the linked list and adds a node after comparing. I wrote a `sortList` previously using collections and it ran perfectly, now I am trying to do it without collections.

My suspicion is that this is easier than I'm making it, and I'm just too close to the code at the moment. Below is the `sortList` and `compareTo` method... the project constructor just contains `firstName` and `lastName`.

```
public int compareTo(linkedListProject arg0) {
    if (this.lastName.equals(arg0.getLastName()))
        return this.firstName.compareTo(arg0.getFirstName());
    else
        return this.lastName.compareTo(arg0.getLastName());
}
```

EDIT (Changed sortList to more accurately utilize compareTo)

```
public static void sortList(linkedListProject a)
{
    Node temp = new Node(a);
    if (head == null)
            {head = temp;}
    else {
        Node cur = head;
        while (cur.next == null && cur.data.compareTo(temp) > 0)
        { cur = cur.next;}
    if (cur.next.data.compareTo(temp) <= 0)
        temp = cur; }
}
```

EDIT once again... Basically I realized Im gonna have to check nodes and insert Nodes as I go, so here is my complete code. sortList has been renamed as addToList. I am still getting nullpointer exceptions

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 * @author Michael Dangelo
 * linkedListProject class, reads from file a provided classRoster then sorts them alphebetically by last name into the linkedList
 *
 */
public class linkedListProject {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private static LinkedList<linkedListProject> classRoster  = new LinkedList<linkedListProject>();

private static class Node
{
    linkedListProject data;
    private Node next = null;

    private Node(linkedListProject data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    private Node(linkedListProject data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public linkedListProject getData()
    {
        return data;

    }

}

private static Node head;

/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public linkedListProject()
{
    head = null;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param firstName First name of student
 * @param lastName  Last Name of Student
 */
public linkedListProject(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public void addToStart(linkedListProject data)
{
    head = new Node(data, head);
}
/**
 * Getter for firstName
 * @return firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() 
{
    return firstName;
}

/**
 * Setter for firstName
 * @param firstName
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
/**
 * Getter for lastName
 * @return lastName
 */
public String getLastName() 
{
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * Setter for Last Name
 * @param lastName
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) 
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

/**
 * toString method used for testing
 */

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "linkedListProject [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
            + lastName + "]";
}



/**
 * compareTo method used in sorting
 */


/**
 * Prints out list to console
 */
public void printList() 
{
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("First Name:     " + "Last Name: ");
    while (count < classRoster.size())
    {
        linkedListProject a = classRoster.get(count);
        System.out.println(a.getFirstName() + "     \t" + a.getLastName());
        count++;
    }

}
/**
 * 
 * @param a linked list ran in 
 */
public static void addToList(linkedListProject a)
{
    Node temp = head;
    Node nextNode = null;
    while (temp != null && nextNode.data.compareTo(a) >=0)
    {
        nextNode = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    if (temp == null)
    {
        Node cur2 = new Node(a);
        cur2.next = head;
        head = cur2;    
        classRoster.add(cur2.getData());
    }
    else {

        Node cur2 = new Node(a);
        cur2.next = temp;
        if (nextNode == null) {
            nextNode.next = cur2;
            classRoster.add(cur2.getData());
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Reads in students names into object then adds and sorts list based on last name & firstName
 * @param inputFileName The File Name
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public void read(String inputFileName) throws java.io.IOException
{
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFileName));
while(infile.hasNext())
{
String firstName = infile.next();
String lastName = infile.next();

linkedListProject intoList = new linkedListProject(firstName, lastName);
linkedListProject.addToList(intoList);

}
infile.close();
}

/**
 * Driver
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    linkedListProject test = new linkedListProject();
    test.read("179ClassList.txt");
    test.printList();
}

public int compareTo(linkedListProject arg0)
{
    if (this.lastName.equals(arg0.getLastName()))
        return this.firstName.compareTo(arg0.getFirstName());
    else
        return this.lastName.compareTo(arg0.getLastName());
}


}
```

Comment: @smcg It doesn't really matter because the homework tag has been deprecated... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/147639

Comment: It's an expansion of a already submitted homework. Basically what I turned in used Collections, but now I want to do it without collections. Would of used Homework Tag if I could. I may have an idea what to do, use compareTo to determine lettering then use previous Node.next to add it in.

Comment: @JesseWebb I know it's been deprecated, but it might affect someone's  answer because the "no Collections" restriction sounded arbitrary.

Comment: `sortList` doesn't sort at all (it may be a subroutine of a sort, but it itself doesn't sort). Shouldn't it be called `insert`, `insertSorted` or similar?

Comment: Yea I was editing it from my past project, I haven't changed the method name from it.